# How to reshape a Pandas data frame before passing to a Plotly function?

Tags: pandas, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm trying to create a table of data using the **`Table()`** function in `Plotly`.

My data is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

test_df = pd.DataFrame({'Manufacturer':['Mercedes', 'Buick', 'Ford', 'Buick', 'Buick', 'Ford', 'Buick', 'Chrysler', 'Ford', 'Buick', 'Chrysler', 'Ford', 'Buick', 'Ford', 'Ford', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Ford', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Chrysler', 'Buick'],
                          'Metric':['MPG', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score', 'Score'],
                          'Statistic':['External', 'Min', 'Max', 'Average', 'Median', '90th', '95th', '99th', 'Min', 'Max', 'Average', 'Median', '90th', '95th', '99th','Min', 'Max', 'Average', 'Median', '90th', '95th', '99th'],
                          'Value':[22, 3.405, 100.29, 4.62, 4.425, 5.34, 5.83, 7.75, 2.6323, 210, 4.193, 3.28, 5.04, 6.36, 11.01, 3.72, 43, 4.98, 4.82, 5.775, 6.18, 7.182],
                       })
```

I want to be able to create a table that looks like as follows:

```
Manufacturer    Min      Max      Average      Median      90th      95th      99th
Buick           3.405    210      4.62         4.425       5.04      5.83      7.182
Chrysler        3.72     43       4.193        4.82        5.775     6.18      7.75
Ford            2.6323   100.29   4.98         3.28        5.34      6.36      11.01
```

The code to do so looks something as follows (when hard-coded):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go 
go.Figure(go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=["Manufacturer", "Min", "Max",
                    "Average", "Median", "90th",
                    "95th", "99th"],
            font=dict(size=10),
            align="left"
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=[['Buick', 'Ford', 'Chrysler'],    # Headers (could change based on the source file)
                    [3.405, 3.72, 2.6323],            # Min values
                    [210, 43, 100.29],                # Max values
                    [4.62, 4.193, 4.98],              # Average values
                    [4.425, 4.82, 3.28],              # Median values
                    [5.04, 5.775, 5.34],              # 90th percentile values
                    [5.83, 6.18, 6.36],               # 95th percentile values
                    [7.182, 7.75, 11.01]              # 99th percentile values
                   ],
            align = "left")                                     
))
```

[image]

According to the docs at https://plotly.com/python/table/, the `cells` argument argument expects a list of lists and **can take a Pandas data frame** (GREAT!).

Using the example in the docs, the code to pass a Pandas data frame would look something as follows:

```
# THIS IS THE EXAMPLE FROM THE DOCS (SHOWING THE USE OF A DATA FRAME)
fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Table(
    header=dict(values=list(df.columns),
                fill_color='paleturquoise',
                align='left'),
    cells=dict(values=[df.Rank, df.State, df.Postal, df.Population],
               fill_color='lavender',
               align='left'))
])
```

My most valiant attempt at this failed:

Filter by only the 'Score' records:

```
test_df_subset = test_df[(test_df['Metric'] == 'Score') & (test_df['Manufacturer'].isin(['Buick', 'Ford', 'Chrysler']))]
```

Create a pivot table:

```
temp_df = pd.pivot_table(data=test_df_subset,index=['Statistic', 'Manufacturer'])
```

Unstack the pivot table:

```
temp_df.unstack(0)
```

**Question:  how would I reshape my `test_df` data frame to be able to pass it to the `data` and `cells` arguments in the `go.Figure()` function?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `values` argument within `header` with `df.columns.to_list()` and the `values` argument within `cells` with `df.values`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were pretty close, here is one way

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go 

cols_ = ["Manufacturer", "Min", "Max",
         "Average", "Median", "90th",
         "95th", "99th"]
manufacturers = ['Buick', 'Ford', 'Chrysler']

#this is what you are looking for
df_ = (test_df[test_df['Manufacturer'].isin(manufacturers)]
              .set_index(['Manufacturer', 'Statistic'])
               ['Value'].unstack()
               .reset_index()[cols_]
               )

go.Figure(go.Table(
        header=dict(
            values=cols_,
            font=dict(size=10),
            align="left"
        ),
        cells=dict(
            values=df_.T, # note the T here
            align = "left")                                     
))
```

Compare to your method, I think `df_` (in my notation) is equivalent to `temp_df.unstack(0)['Value'].reset_index()[cols_]` with your notation and using `cols_` to order them as expected

Comment: Thank you, @Ben.T.  Your solution works perfectly on test and production data.